# Some animation is visible upon ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using the jquery .remove()

and then using ajax to repopulate by means of .append in a .each loop.

There is an annoying animation, recognizable one when doing the change like Clearing of the ListBox ( ListBox Lenght becomes short) then Populating the ListBox (ListBox length increases)

Is there anyway to not show that part and just populate?

Comment: You can get around this by creating your repopulated data in memory and then swapping out the old data with `jQuery.html()`

Answer (score 0):

Build up your HTML in the node that is not part of the DOM and then replace the existing nodes.

e.g.

```
var newList = $('<ul id="new-list"><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>');
$('#existing-list').replaceWith(newList);
```